# I want to use a variable outside a FOR loop in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a String which I want to use as a parameter in a query. My code is as follows:

```
List<EventPayload> mylist=eventpojo.getEventPayload();

            for(EventPayload array : mylist)
            {
                System.out.println("Comment Text :"+array.getCommentText());
                System.out.println("Comment Type :"+array.getCommentType());
                System.out.println("Comment Id :"+array.getCommentId());
                System.out.println("Email id :"+array.getComment_email());
                String email1=array.getComment_email();
            }

            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jcg-JPA");
            EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

            String email=em.createQuery("SELECT user_id FROM UserInfo WHERE email_id = "+email1).toString();
```

I want to use String email1 outside the loop in the query.How to implement this??

Comment: Well, you may have multiple `email1`s (one for each loop iteration). Which one do you want to use?

Comment: then define email1 OUTSIDE the for loop,

Comment: @marstran: or you might have none at all.

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL-injections. You should use prepared statements to put variables into your query.

Comment: @FrankPuffer True :)

Comment: Note that `em.createQuery(...).toString()` will return the query's string representation not the query result. Besides that please read the comments about which email1 you want to use if there are multiples or even none and about the SQL-injection vulnerability (since you're using JPA as indicated by `em` create the `Query` object and use `setParameter(pos/name, value)` instead).

Comment: @Thomas I will go foe getuniqueresult..I just need that email1 outside the loop

Comment: sounds like a bad idea

Comment: If you go for a unique result then why are you starting with a list in the first place? And what should the result be for 2 calls in which I provide the same emails just in different order (e.g. `mail1@so.com,mail2@so.com` and later `mail2@so.com,mail1@so.com`)?  Btw, you're selecting a user id but name the variable that I guess should take the query result `email`.

Comment: I just want user_id which I will be inserting into another table in the database

Answer (score 0):

**email1** is inside the forloop so the scope is reduced to that segment...

declaring that outside, will set the scope of the variable to be accessable outside too...

```
List<EventPayload> mylist=eventpojo.getEventPayload();
String email1=null;  //HERE!!
for(EventPayload array : mylist)
{
    System.out.println("Comment Text :"+array.getCommentText());
    System.out.println("Comment Type :"+array.getCommentType());
    System.out.println("Comment Id :"+array.getCommentId());
    System.out.println("Email id :"+array.getComment_email());
    email1=array.getComment_email();
}

EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jcg-JPA");
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

String email=em.createQuery("SELECT user_id FROM UserInfo WHERE email_id = "+email1).toString();
```

Comment: By doing so only the last email is used within the SQL

Comment: I had tried this earlier..after doing this I get an error of duplicate variable at email1=array.getComment_email(); inside the loop

Comment: ***email1=array.getComment_email();*** is only assigning not declaring, so there is no dupl variable...

Answer (score -1):

short answer: you can't

long answer/further question:
What do you want to to?

Fire a SQL for each EventPayload -> then do this in the loop

Fire a SQL for one distinct EventPayload -> look in the list for the object (or filter the list) and execute the query for this object